# How do I refer to a ' in the path of a SSRS data-driven subscription

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am writing a data driven subscription in SSRS and unfortunately the folder I am writing to is written FY'15.
I can't change this.

Does anyone know how I refer to this path in the subscription?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: Doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Did you test it with other paths to make sure it works?  What error message are you receiving?  Did you check the trace logs?

Comment: Please be more specific. What does "doesn't recognize it" mean? Did it tell you "I don't recognize that", or did it give you "file not found", or did it give you a bad attitude?

Comment: I have no way to test it in SQL as it won't run the query.

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near '15'.
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' as Path

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use double single quotes, or use `CHR(39)`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to save the Generated report in a shared directory which has the Folder Name "FY'15". Try the following.

- Add an extra column, say `FolderPath`, in the query that drives your report. The Value of this column will be the Path of your target folder. You can write it as `select 'C:\folder1\folder2\FY''15' as FolderPath`
- Then, while setting up the subscription, select `Get the value from the database` and set it to the `FolderPath` column.

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: That is true- I think I over simplified though.  I am doing the same thing- but it has to run 137 times and place it in 137 different parent folders.  Here is the actual path I am using but it is still hiccupy.

,'\\server\Hospitals\'+foldername+'\FY''15\PAW Plan Production' as Path

Comment: Foldername is a field in the query to spread it to the individual hospitals top folder.

Comment: are you typing this in the path or generating it as a field from the query and then using that field in the path?

Comment: Typing it as the path.

Comment: Guess I could add it to the table but didn't really want to go that route.

Comment: no need to add to the table. create a new field as '\\server\Hospitals\'+foldername+'\FY''15\PAW Plan Production' and use it in the path. if you type it in the path, it doesnt recognise the `foldername` column.